# Insert column names into stored procedure SELECT statement from separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out the best method to insert column names held in Table1 into a SELECT statement running against Table2. This query is running in a stored procedure. That doesn't do a very good job of explaining, so lets say I had these values in Table1:

[image]

What I am trying to do is use these column names in the SELECT statement against Table2:

```
Select -- Column Names
from Table2
where UserId = 3;
```

I'm not sure if an input parameter could be used in that way or how to pass the values into it. For example:

```
Select @ColumnNames
from Table2
where UserId = 3;
```

Or maybe a join to table 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use Dynamic SQL

```
declare @columns varchar(1000)
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @columns='', @sql=''

select @columns=@columns+value+',' from table1

set @columns=left(@columns,len(@columns)-1)
set @sql='select '+@columns+' from table2'
exec(@sql)
```

But beware of SQL Injection and read www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Dynamic Sql scares me from a security perspective, but I may have to make the best of it if it is the only option

Comment: You should make the variables nvarchar and use `sp_executeSQL` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the system tables to get the column(s) i.e. (take out WHERE clause to see all the tables and columns)

```
SELECT tab.name AS TableName,
  col.name AS ColName, 
  tp.name AS SType,
  col.max_length,
  col.[precision],
  (CASE col.is_nullable 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'true'
         WHEN 0 THEN 'false'
         ELSE 'unknown'
   END) AS Is_Nullable
FROM sys.tables as tab
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns AS col
  ON tab.object_id = col.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS tp
  ON col.system_type_id = tp.system_type_id
WHERE tab.name = 'Table1'
ORDER BY tab.name,col.name
```